# Make Excel List from non-Empty values of column

Tags: excel, vba, list, function

I have an excel sheet whose columns A:AC contain names.

In every row below that name (Rows 2:2000), there is either a blank or the name of a company. 
These rows and columns are dynamic and constantly updating, and I cannot delete the blank cells.

I need to make a list of all the companies each person picked, but I do not want the blank cells to be included in the list.

Is there a way to do this without creating a new column that excludes the blank cells? If not, how can I make the new column dynamic so that when the rows are updated they are included in the drop down list?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Best way I can think of would be to have a script that instead removes all the blanks from a given column and then pushes the data up. Why can't you delete the blank cells? could you re-arrange it so that you have the blank cells below the filled cells?

Comment: Add examples of how your columns look like